# Stuck trying to install "caret" package in R

Tags: r, installation, compilation, package, caret

I'm trying to install the `caret` package in `R`. I run the following code and get the following message.

```
install.packages("caret")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
pROC 1.18.2 1.18.4              TRUE
```

When I get to this point, the code seems to be stuck. I've looked up the issue and everything I've seen says there is a prompt asking whether or not to `install from sources the package which needs compilation?` I do not get this prompt however, and my code remains stuck with the message I showed above. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of sessionInfo() as well as your version of R.
As an aside, do you have Rtools and devtools installed?